# Read csv file to arraylist object

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

The problem lies in the `CVSParser` class. I need to read the .CSV file then pass it off to the `ArrayList<Club>`

**Example.csv**
Team,W,D,L,GF,GA
Arsenal,24,7,7,68,41
Aston Villa,10,8,20,39,61
...

**Club class**

```
public Club(String team, int w, int l, int d, int GF, int GA) {
        ...
    }
```

**CSVParser class**

```
public static ArrayList<Club> CSVParser(String file) throws IOException{

        ArrayList<Club> Lists = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        scanner.nextLine();

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(line);

            /*will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error */
            String[] splits = line.split(",");
            Lists.add(new Club(splits[0], Integer.parseInt(splits[1]),Integer.parseInt(splits[2]), 
                    Integer.parseInt(splits[3]), Integer.parseInt(splits[4]), Integer.parseInt(splits[5])));

        }scanner.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(Lists);
        return Lists;
```

Comment: Your post begins with "the problem is at the..." but your post neglects to even begin to describe a problem.

Comment: Why are you passing a `FileReader` to your `Scanner` instead of a `File`?

Answer (score 1):

First, this is the right way to use scanner

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(",");
int w = s.nextInt());
```

otherwise, just use a BufferedReader

Next, you have one or more empty lines in csvfile, you should check for the line length before splitting, something like:

```
if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
    String[] splits = line.split(",");
}
```